# Do I have to deserialize the whole complex json file (with many nested arrays and objects) when I need only one object? Flutter, Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

https://github.com/[enter link description here](https://github.com/PoojaB26/ParsingJSON-Flutter/blob/master/assets/page.json)PoojaB26/ParsingJSON-Flutter/blob/master/assets/page.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a tiny JSON file and there is no reason for premature optimizations.

Just deserialize it and then access the items of the generated Dart data structures to get what you need. Everything else is probably equally expensive and won't buy you anything.

Comment: This is just example of complex json,   what if complex json has 1000 lines of data?

Comment: I don't think it changes much for bigger files except perhaps for huge files and 1000 lines is still not much.